# HERE.com Routing API: cannot calculate routing for trucks

Tags: routes, here-api

I am using here.com to calculate truck routes.
This has been working without any problems until recently.
I can no longer get routes for trucks that avoid tolls (it works for cars).

This used to work but no longer does:

http://tce.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=XXXXXXXXXX&app_code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&jsonAttributes=41&alternative=1&waypoint0=geo!42.1194581627883,24.735803604126&waypoint1=geo!48.827672057398,2.40594685077667&detail=1&currency=BGN&height=3.2m&width=2.3&length=8&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=0&trailersCount=0&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=0&hybrid=0&emissionType=5&trailerHeight=0cm&vehicleWeight=7557kg&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&passengersCount=1&tiresCount=6&commercial=1&shippedHazardousGoods=0&heightAbove1stAxle=285cm&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled;tollroad:-2&trucktype=truck&limitedWeight=7557kg&weightPerAxle=4100kg&vehicletype=diesel,25&departure=2018-08-03T01:14:17&rollup=none&linkattributes=all&legattributes=li,le,sm&routeattributes=wp,lg,sh&maneuverattributes=all&language=en-GB&instructionformat=html&alternatives=2

This used to work. Is there anything that needs to be changed?

Best regards,
Nuno Almeida

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a valid API call for which the router simply cannot find a valid route. I have tested two things.

First, I have run your exact API call but with different coordinates and I received a valid response with a route. This indicates to me that the API call is well constructed.

Second, I have run an API call for your coordinates, but in car mode and without any of the truck/toll limitations in your request. This also gave me a valid response with a route.

I would therefore conclude that there simply is no valid route between your two waypoints given your restrictions. This is also confirmed by the "NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED_CHECK_OPTIONS" error message, which indicates that the routing graphs for your specific options is not connected and there simply is no valid route.

Try relaxing some of your restrictions to see if you can find what precludes a valid route for these specific waypoints.